# Expose interface to WCF client

Tags: wcf, interface

I have a WCF service which is working fine. Apart from DataContracts and ServiceContracts, I have few Interfaces, which I want to make available to client. Is there any way to expose them to client. Those interfaces are not being used in any methods or property of SC or DC respectively. I cannot go by shared assembly approach, and proxy generation (now) is done using svcutil.exe

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these interfaces? Why does the client need to retrieve them from the service?

Comment: Why is long story, those interfaces required to implement certain functionality. There are other work around but if I could expose them, it will be good